# Python random.choice() in loop with if-function - how to assign value to each iteration

Tags: python, function, loops

I am running a for-loop which prints a value for random.choice (either "black" or "red") for each iteration. That works fine, however assigning the random.choice in the if condition does not seem to work:

```
import random

def randomcolour():
    foo = ['black', 'red']

    for i in range(10):
        random.choice(foo)
        print(i, random.choice(foo))
        if random.choice(foo) == "black":
            print(i, "black")
        else:
            print(i, "red")

randomcolour()
```

What happens here is that the first execution of "random.choice(foo)" randomly chooses "black" or "red". However, the "random.choice(foo)" in the if-function does obviously choose another random value, instead using the same random value previously chosen.

For example, if the first print statement...

```
 print(i, random.choice(foo))
```

...prints out "black", the statement after that (in the same loop iteration)...

```
if random.choice(foo) == "black":
            print(i, "black")
```

...should also print out "black". However, it seems to print out randomly "black" or "red" regardless. How can I fix that? In other words, how do I use the first selected random value for the full loop iteration?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what an assignment statement does. Simply assign the first call to `random.choice` to a variable and then reuse that variable across the current iteration.

```
for i in range(10):
     rand = random.choice(foo)
     print(i, rand)
     if rand == "black":
         ...
```

Comment: works fine! thanks for that. tried that one before but made the mistake to assign the variable after calling random.choice(foo).

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this issue by assigning the first call of random.choice to a variable and then reference that variable. So something like this should work:

```
import random

def randomcolour():
    foo = ['black', 'red']
    for i in range(10):
        mychoice = random.choice(foo)
        print(i, mychoice)
        if mychoice == "black":
            print(i, "black")
        else:
            print(i, "red")

randomcolour()
```